# mouse wheel scrolling, keyboard down key scrolling does not work in SCROLL VIEWER

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

No type of Scrolling works within scroll viewer control in silverlight

> I would like to allow the user to
>   scroll using the mouse wheel

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's there by default unless you're handling the mouse wheel event before it gets to the scroll viewer.